# Closing chrome custom tab

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

In my use case, I have a page that deep links back to my app. When I open this page in Chrome custom tab, I am able to get back to my app by clicking the deep link but the issue is when I click on the device back button, the chrome tab is still visible.

Is there any way I can close the chrome custom tab when the user is back to my app/activity.

Comment: I don't know, but this may help: https://crbug.com/545446

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting the below flag while opening chrome custom tab seems to resolve the issue for me
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: I came across the same issue. 
As per your answer I am adding the flag as: 
`mCustomTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(mCustomTabsSession).build();
mCustomTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);` before launching the custom tabs. but its not solving issue. Is there something which I am missing?

Comment: not working for me either? Any one else have any luck with this?

Comment: @arun, My chrome tab disappears when I press home button and come back to screen.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jaspinder Kaur mentioned: you need to add this on your flag:

```
mCustomTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build(); 
mCustomTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HI‌​STORY)
```

AND:

If you set your app to be `singleInstance` or `singleTop`, then when you go back to it using an intent, the framework will finish Custom tab activity as well.